# What background do I need to have before starting Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

Like: basics of electrical circuits, etc..

In order to go far in Arduino and electronics.

Answer (score 7):

I am a Electrical technician and bought the starter kit from the Arduino team for my 13 year old son. My plan was to try the kit to teach my son about electronics.

The end result is that he is the one showing me new stuff.

In my opinion, you do not need any special background before starting with Arduino. You should have a interest in learning something new, and in learning about electronics. To get started, buy a tutorial book and a starter kit. (Many starter-kits comes with a tutorial book) When you have gone through the book, you will have some basic knowledge and a base to continue learning from.

Good luck

Comment: It might help alot to have some basic knowledge about the law of Ohm etc. It may be that these tutorial books of Arduino will explain these thingss since I've never bought such a book. 

When you've finished the book you might consider to continue learning from other example projects for Arduino on the internet and reading lots of datasheets. Try to open some applications and rebluid small parts of it with your Arduino. 

Oh, and not to forget. Read the datasheet of the Arduino before experimenting your self so you won't blow it up. (How many volts can an Arduino recieve, how many amps etc)

Answer (score 0):

You need a basic understanding of programming because you will need to program in C++.
You need basic computer literacy, but I bet you've got that if you are on this website.
You need some understanding of electronics, such as a High-School level textbook. You need to understand resistors, diodes, voltages, current etc. Otherwise you'll get very frustrated.

Comment: While knowing all this helps, this is not actually true. It is possible to, as they say, learn.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn some absolute basics about electronics so you don't fry your arduino. (Don't exceed the current limits on the i/o pins. How to use Ohm's Law to calculate current. How to tie inputs to ground with a resistor. How to tie inputs to +5 through a resistor.  How to estimate the total current load of your entire circuit to make sure it doesn't overload the +5 regulated power from the Arduino. Basic precautions against static electricity.)

Beyond that, it makes a great learning tool, and you should be able to learn as you go. Build the sample projects that are on the Arduino website.

You might want to buy a book on logic circuits. I read "The CMOS Cookbook" years ago, and it gave me a good strong grounding.

You'll also want to learn programming, since you need to use C or C++. Again, though, you can use the Arduino as a learning tool. Looking at the sketches from the website and modifying them will help you learn.